# python from hex to shellcode format

Tags: python, format, hex, shellcode

I try to convert a hex string to shellcode format
For example: I have a file in hex string like `aabbccddeeff11223344`
and I want to convert that through python to show this exact format:
`"\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x11\x22\x33\x44"` including the quotes `""`.

My code is:

```
with open("file","r") as f:
    a = f.read()
    b = "\\x".join(a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2))
    print b
```

so my output is `aa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x11\x22\x33\x44\x`.

I understand I can do it via sed command but I wonder how I may accomplish this through python.

Answer (score 2):

The `binascii` standard module will help here:

```
import binascii

print repr(binascii.unhexlify("aabbccddeeff11223344"))
```

Output:

```
>>> print repr(binascii.unhexlify("aabbccddeeff11223344"))
'\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x11"3D'
```

Comment: Thank you. So the output is missing \x22\x33\x44.
I got the error "Type Error: Odd-length string".

Comment: @kluo, no, the output of the code in my answer _is not_ missing anything and the code _is not_ causing any errors. Please double-check how you run it and keep in mind that `'\x44' == 'D'`, `'\x33' == '3'` and `'\x22' == '"'`, which is exactly what this code produces.

Comment: Oh I see. Can we keep the original hex format somehow?

Comment: @kluo, I believe there's no need to: the compiler will deal with the mix of hex-escapes and literal ASCII characters just fine. They are _the same thing_.

Comment: I have put aabbccddeeff11223344 to a file call 'test':
and following code:
import binascii
with open ("test","r") as f:
    a = f.read()
    b = repr(binascii.unhexlify(a))
    print b
and I got TypeError: Odd length string. That's weird

Comment: @kluo, there's a newline or a space at the end of file.